# How to break the limitation of ASP.NET webservice?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services, performance, optimization

I'm writing a ASP.NET webservice (.ASMX), and to test this webservice, I'm using a client application which creates 100 threads, 3 requests/each thread. When I run 10 iterations, the client takes about 60-70 seconds, which means about 3000 requests/minutes, and I can't manage to take over that number, even when I run the client and the webservice on same machine. I checked all the statuses of machine: RAM, hard-disk, CPU,... all the statuses are OK (very low-load, CPU below 6%, RAM about 80% free,...), and the bottle-neck is the webservice itself.

I tried WCF, but it performs worse than the ASMX in my benchmark, and  because of my deadline, I can't spend too much time to study deeper WCF.

So how can I optimize my webservice? How can I break the limitation of ASP.NET webservice? Is it possible to manage to get a webservice to perform up to 5000 request/second?

Thank you very much.

Comment: have you tried async web requests?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it yet. Can you give me more details?

Comment: sorry, one sec, I'll find some resourses for you

Comment: Added info, though it sounds like the tools I mentioned are what you are after - you'll be able to work out when you server falls over with them... but you might want to think about creating a "User Profile" and try to emulate many users accessing you service, rather than just calling web methods many times without any pattern.

Comment: Can you please explain more detail about User Profile? A method of this webservice is used intensively, and I generate random data for each call. The webservice itself is protected by the OS (IP filter), and will be called anonymous

Comment: Does your web service use any shared resources? If so, you could look at how you're controlling access to those shared resources.

Comment: I suspect the problem might be with your test. Can you test with more than one client machine?

Comment: No, the webservice uses itself resource, which is all cached on the RAM, and it should not be problem.

Comment: User profile - I mean emulate what a user would do instead of concentrating on one web method (maybe this isn't applicable to your service) but, for example - with ours, there's the log on process, then get various data, modify that data, get more data, do some other stuff, log off. Just saying it might help to follow what your users would do to see what your load really is rather than hammering one web method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to trying [asynchronous web requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx) - though there is an easier way of doing this - I think it is in the properties of the web service reference that allows the async methods (and related completed event) to be generated in the web service proxy,.

Have a look at [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/) and [LOADUI](http://www.loadui.org/), they are tools that could help you.